# How to install module 'keras'?

Tags: python, keras

I am following the article https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/10/predicting-stock-price-machine-learningnd-deep-learning-techniques-python/ . After copy and paste the following code:

```
    #importing required libraries
    from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM

    #creating dataframe
    data = df.sort_index(ascending=True, axis=0)
    new_data = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,len(df)),columns=['Date', 'Close'])
    for i in range(0,len(data)):
        new_data['Date'][i] = data['Date'][i]
        new_data['Close'][i] = data['Close'][i]

...
```

I get an error: "No module named 'keras'. I search online and find I need to install keras module. In the article https://github.com/antoniosehk/keras-tensorflow-windows-installation , there is a step-by-step guide on how to install keras. However, it requires Nvida graphic card for GPU while I only have an integrated Intel graphic card. Therefore, I try to find another link at https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-optimization-for-tensorflow-installation-guide that works for Intel graphic card, so I install tensorflow as follows:

```
conda install tensorflow-mkl
```

During the installation, I can see one package is called keras-xxx, so I belive keras is also installed. But after the installation, when I try to run the code, I still get the error. Why?

Thanks

Comment: `conda install keras`

Comment: @HSK, Thank you very much. I try the command and keras is installed successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have CUDA supports GPU (NVIDEA Series), I strongly recommend you to install tensorflow-gpu from the aconda forge by conda command (not by pip) because the tensorflow-gpu needs a lot of requirments such as CUDA, CuDNN and etc that caused too hard to configurate all together correctly. if use the conda all the packages install together easily (without any tears!!!)

```
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu
```

but if you want to use cpu, you can easily install tensorflow by the pip or conda